Gradle task assembleDebug failed while attempting to connect to Firebase
I was trying to connect my flutter app to firebase and I suddenly got this error. My VS code is not showing any red squiggle but it's saying the "Gradle task assembleDebug failed". This is the error I am facing :


I tried restarting the app as well as the system but it didn't solve the issue. At first my errors were at allproject in build.gradle (project root) and then in app build.graddle -

 -
Can someone explain what is wrong and how to solve this problem?

Try to add this code in your main.dart file inside main()  method -WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();   await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);

Didn't work, it is showing error

what was the error?

it is showing - Error: The plugin "firebase_auth" requires a higher minimum iOS deployment version than your application is targeting.
